# C# OAuth Jira Connection

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, jira-rest-api

I am having trouble connecting to JIRA with a C# WebApi. I have gone through the steps on Jira's side to create my secret key.

Here is the code I have that is trying to get a token:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUrl);

// We want the response to be JSON.
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

// Build up the data to POST.
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type",    "client_credentials"));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id",     _consumerKey));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", _consumerSecret));

FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

// Post to the Server and parse the response.
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/plugins/servlet/oauth/request-token", content);
string jsonString            = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
object responseData          = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

// return the Access Token.
return ((dynamic)responseData).access_token;
```

I am getting a BadRequest status code and when I read the Content it comes as `oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key&oauth_problem=parameter_absent`.

I am using the correct parameter for the ClientID field, right? I am using OauthKey, which I am getting from the following picture within Jira:

[image]